# Correct way for create .cs file from an .svc with WCF

Tags: c#, web-services

A have a .Net Solution with a webservice and its unit tests.
The webservice has its .svc and from the test project i need the .cs (generated, as far as i know, from the url of the service. Somthing like this `svcutil.exe [WebServiceUrl]`).

To automate the unit test i need this .cs updated on the test project in every build so i added a pre-build event wich calls svcutil.exe to obtain the wsdl and generate the .cs. This step needs the service to be running but i need to create it from the project itself i dont want the service to be running to create the .cs. Is there a way to do this? or another approach?

Comment: How will you know if the service has been updated if it isn't running?

Comment: Are you trying to unit test the Reference.cs file or the service itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could self-host the WCF service in a separate assembly used only for this purpose, then run svcutil.exe to get the WSDL output and generate the .cs file from it.

Of course, this would mean you have to build the WCF host assembly first, then run svcutil.exe, then build your unit test assembly and the rest of the assemblies in your solution.  This could all be done with a pre-build activity in your build workflow.